# "Killed: 9" error when trying to construct a Scipy csr_matrix from a large NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to solve a Markov chain problem in which the transition matrix contains about ~150,000 rows and columns, which is however sparse (only about ~450,000 elements are nonzero).

I notice that trying to construct a `csr_matrix` matrix from a `np.zeros` array of that size leads to a `Killed: 9` error:

```
In [139]: N = 150000

In [140]: T = np.zeros((N, N))

In [142]: import scipy.sparse

In [143]: _T = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(T)
Killed: 9
```

Is it possible to construct a `csr_matrix` of this size? Do I need to initiate the matrix `T` as a `csr_matrix` and dispense with NumPy arrays altogether?

Comment: I guess the problem is that you create this large dense matrix `T`. Why don't you directly create the sparse matrix with `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((N, N))`?

Comment: Read the docs for the different sparse formats.  Filling a blank csr format incrementally is a bad idea.

Comment: How do you generate those 450,000 nonzero values?  Creating a blank sparse matrix is easy but practically useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your process is "killed: 9" mostly because the process is taking too long or too much memory of the system and it's been terminated by the os. Just like in the comment, you can construct a sparse matrix directly using `csr_matrix`:

```
_T = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((N,N))
```